# Area of square that is inscribed in a circle that is also inscribed in a rhombus

Tags: geometry, circles

> A circle is inscribed in a rhombus whose diagonals are $17 cm$ and $27 cm$. What is the area of square inscribed on the same circle?

**Solution:**

Centred at the origin, one side can lie on the line $\frac{x}{(13.5)} + \frac{y}{(8.5)} = 1$.
The square of the distance from the origin to the line/side $\frac{x}{(13.5)} + \frac{y}{(8.5)} = 1$ is $\frac{1}  {\frac{1}{(13.5)^2}} + \frac{4}{(8.5)^2}$ which is $\frac{210681}{4072}$ which is half the area of the inscribed square is which is $\frac{210681}{2036}cm²$.

[image: My diagram presentation]

**Question:**

Is $\frac{210681}{2036}cm²$ correct? Or is there something wrong with my solution?

Comment: The approach is correct, assuming you haven’t made any calculation errors.

Comment: I've got the same number. But you can get the radius of the circle in a simpler way. Notice that the diagonals are perpendicular, and the radius of the circle is perpendicular to the sides of the rhombus at the tangency points. Then write the area of the triangle in one of the quadrants using the product of the sides of the triangles, and using the height and the hypotenuse: $$\frac12 \frac{17}{2}\frac{27}{2}=\frac12 R\sqrt{\left(\frac{17}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{27}{2}\right)^2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $r$ be the circle of the radius. Then,

$$r=\frac{a_1a_2}{\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}}$$

with $a_1$ and $a_2$ being the half diameters of the rhombus. Then, the area of the square is
$$ Area = 2r^2 = \frac{2\left( \frac{17}2 \cdot\frac{27}2\right)^2}{{\left(\frac{17}2\right)^2+\left(\frac{27}2\right)^2}}  = \frac12\cdot\frac{(17\cdot27)^2}{17^2+27^2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can compute the area of the rhombus as $(17)(27)/2 = 459/2$, but since this area is also equal to the diameter of the inscribed circle multiplied by a side length, it follows that $$d = \frac{459}{2\sqrt{(17/2)^2 + (27/2)^2}} = \frac{459}{\sqrt{1018}}.$$  The area of the square is simply $$\frac{d^2}{2} = \frac{210681}{2036}.$$